# Filter pandas rows based on trend in values

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have the following table in pandas:

| Client | Evol_2019 | Evol_2020 | Evol_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Juice Factory | 0 | 1 | -1 |
| Food Factory | -1 | 0 | -2 |
| Cloth Factory | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to display only rows which observe a trend over the years, that is to say which have multiple negative or positive values in their evolutions. In that case, only *Food Factory* would be displayed.

I didn't find any conditions satisfying this requirement, any idea ?

Comment: You need to define a condition. See, you write "which have multiple negative or positive values in their evolutions" (note the POSITIVE) and claim that only Food Factory would be displayed. Why not Cloth Factory? It also has a "trend" that you claim you could consider.

Comment: @Serge de Gosson de Varennes Thanks for the remark !
My idea was that it would need to be replicated over the years in order to be considered a trend. In other words, have 2 cells or more having a similar sign, positive or negative. My bad if it was not properly worded !

Comment: Is it possible to have a row with values like [-1, 1, -2] ?   In that case, it is not all values <= 0 while still fit into what you mentioned "multiple negative or positive values in their evolutions"

Comment: @SeaBean Hey, sorry for not coming back to you in time. There is a margin for freedom in my requirements, so that will depend on what is the most simple. Currently, it wouldn't show up as a trend, and that fits my expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "trend" is that all values are smaller or equal to zero, you could do this:

```
df = df[(df <= 0).all(1)]
```

Consider this example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3))
```

that is,

```
   0         1         2
0 -0.888926  0.058545 -1.256491
1  0.477024 -2.519239 -0.110326
2  1.884556  0.714018  0.977505
3  0.132514 -1.374656 -0.727327
4  0.219045  0.354403 -0.183413
5  0.343402 -0.302415 -0.372308
6 -0.699375 -0.492723  0.694994
7  1.460814 -0.294340 -1.305795
8 -0.177625  0.499749  0.001147
9 -0.575742 -0.148443 -1.766909
```

then

```
df[(df <= 0).all(1)

     0         1         2
9 -0.575742 -0.148443 -1.766909
```

However, you need to be more precise with what you mean by trend.

Comment: Just applied it to my main dataset, works wonders. Thanks for the extra effort of interpretation. Have a great day !